# long format's file+date+rights

Tags: unix

How can I list in long format all files (located in a directory ) which belong to me (rights) and modified more than 7 days?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "find" command, it has many options, including creation time, access time, modified time, and you can run commands on any files it finds etc.

Comment: Look at the `-mmin` and `-uid` or `-user` primaries.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively find files of user "maalem", modified more than 7 days ago, list in long format

```
find . -type f -user maalem -mtime +7 -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Comment: Instead of the exec ls he could also use finds printf function

Answer (score 0):

`find` will help you.

You just asked just a little bit earlier a similar question, maybe you should have closer look at the find man-page